# NPM commands do not work in vs code terminal

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-start

I have been trying to use npm commands like npm start in the vs code terminal but it just gives me a option to open the file in a application. Any way to fix this or which app should I open it in. When I select something like google chrome it just opens the file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJUYg.jpg

Right now ive resulted in using a .bat file just to cd to the location and npm start from there and it works and I see my app on localhost

Comment: Some NPM commands can be entered as just **`npm + (Command)`**, but most need to be entered as **`npm run + (Command)`** . And, obviously, don't include the + sign, lol.

Comment: If that doesn't help you, then you will need to run the command, and edit in 3 things, the error message that you are getting, a screen shot of your editor with the terminal displayed, imeadiatly after the command fails to execute properly (or as expected), and lastly, we will need to see your package.json file, you can C&P it, or screen shot it if its small enough to see the whole file in a photo.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fnztxbQ
https://ibb.co/p4fJgBs
https://ibb.co/86vSpYW

Here are the pictures

Comment: Ok I see you posted the pictures, give me a few minutes to look them over

Comment: Okay so when you use the `npm start` command, you can do it without using run. There are a few that do not have to use run, however; when you use any arbitrary customized command the command is entered like this `npm run start` or `npm run test:index`. Thats why you  got an error using run. When you used the command `npm start` the command executed, and it did so without error. That tells me the command you are using isn't correct. What I would like you to did now, assuming you still want to fix this, is go into your package.json file and change your

Comment: I ran outta room, so, as I was saying: "...what I want you to do is change the start command in your package.json file so that it echos _Hello World!_. The command should look like this.  **`"start": "echo \"Hello World\""`**. (you will want to escape the quotes around `echo`'s string argument as I did in the example. After you change the start script, execute it via **`npm start`** or **`npm run start`**. It should print Hello World! in the console. If it doesn't then you need to get it too, if you can't get it working take another picture for me, so I can see what result you are getting.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It still isnt working and doesnt print anything. It just opens the select application screen.

Comment: Okay we gotta get it to echo. Start by using echo in your terminal, to ensure you know how to use the echo command in windows. One you successfully echo in the terminal, attach the same echo command that you used in the terminal to the npm start command in your package.json. Once we get it to echo, then we know we have a working npm command, and can rule out npm. This is typical for solving issues, its called "solution by way of elimination"